# Fleet Run Configuration Maven Build

Tags: java, maven, jetbrains-ide, run-configuration, fleet

I'm new on Fleet, I'm trying to import maven project, I created a run.json with this configuration:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "maven",
            "name": "Maven Clean Install",
            "workingDir": "./",
            "tasks": ["clean"]
        },
        
    ]
}
```

but when I run it got this error:

```
"C:\Program" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
```

**run.json & error:**

[image]

**settings.json**

[image]

**Fleet Maven Settings**

[image]

I would make a maven run configuration clean install, now I'm trying only with clean to semplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to configure the path to your Maven executable to use quotation marks for any folder where a space exists, like so:

#### Before:

`C:\Program Files\maven...`

#### After:

`C:\"Program Files"\maven...`

Comment: I can't add quotation marks in fleet settings, I solved moving the maven folder without space. Thanks!